# C# MStest sad flow Unit test error with System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to make a sad flow uniting testing. It keeps failing in the way I am expecting it to be. What is the problem what my code or test?
The error message shows

> Test method threw exception System.ArgumentException, but exception Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.UnitTestAssertException was expected. Exception message: System.ArgumentException: You have to put an password

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f8vk.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjHeL.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wedEx.png

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f8vk.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjHeL.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wedEx.png

Comment: It's my first time asking a question, idk how to add a picture in the question but those are my UserClass entities, the test constructor, and my test. I hope that provides enough information to tell what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your code in your question as text, not as images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 for a number of reasons why.